# How to add specific categories in robots.txt file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4, robots.txt

I want to stop some categories from being crawled. So i decided to add the category paths in robots.txt file. But i am not sure about the syntax. How can i achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Robots.txt For Magento](https://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/robots-txt-for-magento/)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: http://yoursite.com/category/category.html
```

Comment: is it disallow those category products also?

Comment: I don't know about this.